# Should I install Ubuntu or Xubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, 12.10, xubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out which version and derivate of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minmal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC before, and I found it slow. I also had another problem with 12.10 once it was installed. My computer has 734MB of RAM, and for this reason I created a swap partition of about 1.5GB.

Should I install Ubuntu 12.04 or Xubuntu?

I have 734MB of RAM and a 1.6Ghz processor.

Comment: why not go with [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you install ubuntu, see how it works and if you want the lower powered desktop you can always run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: do you think that ubuntu 12.04 can be on my pc without a lot of problems ??

Comment: Well on my home PC i found that that 12.04 was slow, i have 2gb of ram and a fast dual core centrino processor, not the best but not bad and its about 4-5 years old. I found that 12.10 works just fine on it... Well lags here and there but an improvement on 12.04. Can you access the desktop on you installation? if so i'd run that command on you 12.10 install and see how the xubuntu desktop runs for you, it might mean a bit less work for you.

Comment: Just as a side note so you know. The command i gave you will install the xubuntu desktop on top of you current install of ubuntu and then on the loggin screen you will be able to choose which desktop to load.

Comment: I installed ubuntu 12.10 and when I log in it give me a problem ; it says quantal problem . Have you a solution ? Thank you

Comment: I don't know about that, never seen an error like that before I'm sorry to say. But if you do roll back to 12.04 you can still install the xubuntu desktop and that should be a bit easier on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 in old pc with 500MB RAM and I worked but sometimes get hanged up.
I tried some GUI in the same Ubuntu 12.04 installation and **xfce** and **xubuntu** work with no problem.

I hope this helps.